# MySQL complex confusion

Tags: php, mysql

How to update single cell from several locations.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

I will update the row with the following command. This needs's to be updated from several computer's at the same time.

Can you please guide me how to solve it.

machine 1 send

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

machine 2 send

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

machine 3 send

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

machine 4 send

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

machine 5 send

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";
```

Doing this may leads to data loss in some occasions.

If we fetch data and update will it fix the issue? for example

FETCH

`$query1 = "SELECT users from where Username=pool_data" ;`

UPDATE

`$query2 = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";`

FETCH

`$query1 = "SELECT users from where Username=pool_data"`

UPDATE

`$query2 = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";`

FETCH

`$query1 = "SELECT users from where Username=pool_data"`

UPDATE

`$query2 = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data' WHERE Username ='pool_data'";`

Everytime we post data we fetch and update it. Does this have any possible issues?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a DBMS (database management system). Thus, MySQL gives you tools and ways to manage a database.

The official website (https://www.mysql.com/), contains all the information you need to set up MySQL, create a database and all the information corresponding updating tables.

If you have a specific question about your SQL code or some MySQL setups, just post your SQL statements here or give us more infos describing your problem.

Comment: Sure, if you UPDATE the same row over and over again (username has the same value) you will override the data. It is important to understand that MySQL manages your sql queries. It will start one query after the last transaction has finishied. That means, even if you start all queries from different computers, they will not be processed at the same time. MySQL manages parallelism for you. Obviously, if you update the same data of the same username, you will override your last changes again but this would be a table concept problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean ensuring the integrity of the data in your database.

This can be accomplished by using locking for example. If you use Innodb as your storage engine this will be on by default. It uses locking on row-level, which means that other connections can't write to the row while the initial connection is busy writing.

If you use another engine you might want to use transactions. You will need to think about which type of concurrency you want to use, either pessimistic or optimistic. Optimistic is keeping track of versions of rows to ensure the integrity of the data in it.

For more explanations on using transactions in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question, so I will try to rephrase it. I think you're asking:

> In a scenario where more than 1 client is updating the database, how
>   do you make sure that different clients don't overwrite each other's
>   data?

There is no common answer to this - it all depends...

The simplest solution is to include a version number in each record, so your query would be something like:

```
FETCH

$query1 = "SELECT users from where Username=pool_data" ;

UPDATE

$query2 = "UPDATE users SET data='$final_data', versionID = '$newVersion' WHERE Username ='pool_data' and versionID = '$versionID'";
```

This assumes your client generates the version number; you can also do this via a trigger. This way, if your client has read some data in the past, and another client has modified that data, the update statement will affect zero rows; you can then let the application decide what to do about that.

In this model, the first client "wins" - the first one to update the data doesn't have to manage the clashing data.

A more complex solution removes "update" statements, and instead turns your database into an event stream or ledger.

```
FETCH

$query1 = "SELECT ..., max(entry_date) from where Username=pool_data group by ..." ;

UPDATE

$query2 = "insert into users values (@userName, '$final_data', $now());
```

This works well when the last client should win ,or when you can use some other logic to work out what the true state of the application data is.